# How to duplicate a repo to a new one without affecting the original repo?

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I am new to github and very confused right now...
I successfully started a repo that connected with my localhost Wordpress site.

But now, I would like to clone this site to a remote hosting server, also start a new repo connecting with that remote server.

What I did is, I duplicated my local site folder(just in case any failure happens). And I am trying to create a new repo for this duplicated folder.

But seems, Github still knows this is a duplicate and doesn't allow me to create a brand new repo...

Any ideas? Thank you all~

Answer (score 0):

https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

This should provide you with the information you need. Github has extensive documentation that is user friendly and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new blank repository in Github say name foo. Now add this repo's url as your new origin in your earlier repository using the steps below.

> Replace the **origin** in your **.git/config** file to **foo's url** (backup
>   original config file)

Now do

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Now restore your config file .

Comment: @cafababe, changing internals is not a good solution. Change the answer to run `git remote set-url ...` or `git remote add newlocation ...`